# handshake with the minecraft bukkit server - failed sending server host field

Tags: c++, minecraft, packets

I'm trying to make client/bot for minecraft server to automatically guard chat and ban spammers. (first achievment)
I found some docs here and I've implemented data types [from here](http://wiki.vg/Data_Types) ([so they look like this](http://u8.8u.cz/code/mcadmin/packet_data_types.h) - and I'm not finished yet). Now, I'm trying to send inital `0x02` packet, which should look like this:

#### My packet format

```
size    value                comment

1       0x02                 Packet ID
2+?     string               Username (I send "jakub")
2+?     another string       Server host name - here, the program FAILS*
4       25565                Port number
```

*Fails means that the bukkit server outputs following in the console, and the socket is closed:

> *11:09:45* [INFO] /127.0.0.1:51256 **lost connection**

I can see now way, how to test if my data types are correct, but because I seem to send username with no problem, I think I'm sending **wrong information**, though in **correct format**.

#### Generating string

But anyway, I'm curious if I did everything right. I have class for `mc_short` and `mc_string`. This is how `mc_short` creates 2 bytes of itself:

```
//mc_short::val is type of short 
void mc_short::asBytes(char* data) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       data[endianity?i:1-i] = (val >> (i * 8));  //Some magic with byteshifting.
       //endianity is set to false, because java uses BigEndian everywhere** (UNFRIENDLY PERSONS!!)
}
```

**Refer to http://wiki.vg/Data_Types:

> All types in Java (and as such Minecraft) are big-endian, that is, the most significant byte comes first.

Then the string itself uses the `mc_short` and `std::string` to fill bytes in `char*`.

```
void mc_string::asBytes(char* data) {
    mc_short size((short)val.length());  //val is std::string
    size.endianity = endianity;          //mc_string::endianity is boolean, and is ony used to determine endianity of the first 2 bytes
    size.asBytes(data);  //Filling 2 bytes in data - length info
    for(short i=0; i<size.value(); i++) {
        data[i+2] = val[i];  //Copying std::string to data
    }
}
```

#### Question summary

1. What should I send as "server hostname", the third field of 0x02?
2. Am I sending the string correctly? Isn't there any other conversion required?

I'm aware, that my question is about not very known topic and thus you may not know nor the answer, nor the topic itself. Just ignore the question under such circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings are encoded in big-endian unicode (UTF-16, but big endian). You can't map your characters directly from memory if you aren't using Java (well, you can cheat if you just write a zero between each character and accept that it's a shitty way to do it). There's an example in C# of encoding Minecraft strings [here](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net/blob/master/Craft.Net/MinecraftStream.cs#L276).

As for the contents of that string, it should be the hostname to connect to. If Google ran a Minecraft server, that string might be `minecraft.google.com`.

An example of working with this actual packet is [here](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net/blob/master/Craft.Net/Packets.cs#L91).

So, with your question actually answered, some advice. The Minecraft protocol is terrible and writing a client will take a lot of work. You need to be able to support all packets in the protocol (yes, all of them), and you need to implement basic physics to fall to the ground so you don't get kicked for flying. There are several options, in order from best to worst choice:

- Use Bukkit and write a plugin for this
- Write a proxy instead of a client
- Write a client, like you're trying to now

So, if you do the first, you'll need to write a plugin in Java. I don't know much about this.

I do know a lot about the latter two options. I'm the maintainer of [Craft.Net](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net), which is a bunch of libraries, including a generic networking library, and a client library. You could throw together a client or proxy in a few hours. An example client is in the same repo, and there's a proxy [here](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/SMProxy). These all use C#.

If you still want to totally roll your own, good luck and godspeed.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! :) I'm aware of Craft.Net, but I did not use anything from here yet, because of two reasons. First I always have problems including and using new libraries and second, unless I'm totally lost, I like to figure things out on my own. I'm not going to implement my bot as a Bukkit plugin, because it is also supposed to have other capabilities and because I don't like java. Is there some way to contact you in the cases when I'm lost? (#mcdevs IRC perhaps? I swear I will only bother you when there is no other option.

Comment: Besides above, I already have the bot working with `0x07` forcefield and simple inventory manipulation implemented. So far, my shitty strings caused me no problem :P I'm now ready to write map parser.

Comment: I hang out in #craft.net on Freenode IRC. Feel free to bother me, I don't mind. I'm SirCmpwn.